# Find average amount paid to each doctor

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-tables

```
Create Table Doctor(
    doctorID varchar(50) Primary key,
    doctorFName varchar(50),
);

Create Table Appointment(
    appID varchar(50) Primary Key,
    doctorID varchar(50) Foreign Key References Doctor(doctorID),
);

Create Table Payment(
    paymentID varchar(50) Primary Key,
    paymentAmount int,
    appID varchar(50) Foreign Key References Appointment(appID),
);
```

`paymentAmount` is also known as payment for each appointment

How can I get the average payment amount of each doctor?

I tried:

```
SELECT d.doctorID, d.doctorFName, SUM(p.paymentAmount) as AverageDailySalary 
FROM Payment p JOIN Appointment a ON p.appID = a.appID JOIN Doctor d ON a.doctorID = d.doctorID 
ORDER BY d.doctorID
```

Comment: Can you please also share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: *What you have tried so far* should also included actual (and expected) results.

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple `JOIN..GROUP BY` query :

```
SELECT d.doctorID,d.doctorFName,AVG(p.paymentAmount) as avg_pay
FROM Doctor d
JOIN Appoitment a
 ON(d.doctorID = a.doctorID)
JOIN payment p
 ON(a.appID = p.appID)
GROUP BY d.doctorID,d.doctorFName
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this reveals about the salary of each patient

Comment: I'm not sure where he has hidden the information about patients :X .

Comment: Do you want me to include the patient details also, cause i made the tables simpler for you to understand

Comment: Thank you VERY much SAGI it works, i had the JOIN functions confused